# Login page won't redirect to route to logged-in page

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, fetch, react-router-dom

I've been struggling now with my login page to make the component render the Loggedin component.
I'm having Reactjs for the frontend and a NodeJS backend.
I'm fairly new to nodejs, express and react.

On the loginform component I do a post using fetch which passes the username and password to corresponding endpoint on the backend. No problem.
At the backend it reads the jsonfile where i store users(not using any DB for this project) to find a match and if both username and password match the response it send is true. And i've tested that this works.

LoginForm Frontend:

```js
handleSubmit= (e) => {
    e.preventDefault()
    console.log(this.state)
    const { username, password} = this.state;
    const data = {username: username, password:password}
    
    fetch('http://localhost:3001/Login', {
          method: 'POST',
          mode:'cors',
          body: JSON.stringify(data),
          headers: {
            "Content-type": "application/json"
          }  
        })
        .then(function(res){
          return res.json()}).then(function(resjson){
            console.log(resjson);
            if (resjson){
              console.log(resjson);
              return<Redirect to='/myAccount'/>  
            }
            if(resjson==false){
              console.log(resjson);
            }
          })
           
        }
```

I've been trying to make use of react-router-dom by experimenting. But no matter how i went with it the component for the logged in users never renders evens if resjson is true, not even the route changes to "localhost:3000/myAccount".
I've also tried adding useHistory but that results in an invalid Hook when i add `const history=useHistory();`

Any ideas? If you need me to add anything else i'll do it, since i'm not that experience when it comes to JS i might have left something important out.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Take a look below, i wrote explanations in comments :

```
fetch("http://localhost:3001/Login", {
  method: "POST",
  mode: "cors",
  body: JSON.stringify(data),
  headers: {
    "Content-type": "application/json",
  },
})
  .then(function (res) {
    return res.json();
  })
  .then(function (resjson) {
    console.log(resjson);
    if (resjson) {
      console.log(resjson);
      // here you're returning a React Component and it could work inside  render !
      // return <Redirect to="/myAccount" />;

      // you could use history to redirect:
      // if you're inside a class component you could use withRouter HOC instead (there is a link below)
      return history.push("/myAccount");
    }
    if (resjson == false) {
      console.log(resjson);
    }
  });
```

here is the link for the **[withRouter](https://reactrouter.com/web/api/withRouter)** HOC use.

Comment: i think it should be just history.push because if he call it inside the handler you dont need to return it